# Get the bluetooth storage folder on Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, directory

I want to set a FileObserver in the bluetooth folder. My problem is that this folder is different depending on the device, for example in Galaxy S is "mnt/sdcard/bluetooth" and in the Desire is "mnt/sdcard/downloads/bluetooth". Is there any way to get programatically that folder to be able to do the application device independient?

Thanks.

Santi.

Answer (score 1):

Check this method: [getExternalFilesDir(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). And use [DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) as type.

If you add "bluetooth" to the end you'll get the bluetooth download directory.

Comment: Hi Henridv, thanks for your answerd. But doing that in the Galaxy S I get: /mnt/sdcard/Downloads/bluetooth, but the bluetooth files are stored in the /mnt/sdcard/bluetooth folder instead. There is no DIRECTORY_BLUETOOTH type :-S

Comment: Hmmm, that's true indeed. I'm starting to think the bluetooth downloads folder chosen by the vendor, not Android. So maybe you could do a search for the bluetooth folder and save this in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes, that was my work arround. I did a recursive method searching bluetooth folder in the sdcard. It's funny because I found some device where there are two bluetooth folders, but ofcourse only one of them is storing the files, so when I get the first file I discard other folders. Thanks!!