# Can't access file inside "downloads" on SD card with getExternalStorageDirectory?

Tags: android, bluetooth, filereader

This is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334953/unable-to-print-out-information-from-file-android-application) post but basically I can't access the files that are *inside* of a folder on my device storage but I can access files that are *outside* of any folder.

For example displayCurrentBodyTempArray function works when temp.txt is referenced but not when boyTempTest.txt is referenced that is inside the download folder. And as I don't know how to NOT download something, over bluetooth(which I have to do), and have it go to that folder I am confused. I just can't access that folder. Any help is appreciated!

bodyTempInfo function

```
 ArrayList<Double> currentBodyTemp;

    public void displayCurrentBodyTempArray(View view) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file


//Read text from file

        File file = new File(sdcard, "bodyTempTest-1.txt");

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                list.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }
        currentBodyTemp = list;
        displayBodyTemp("Your Body Temperature Readings are:" + text);
}
```

displayBodyTemp function

```
private void displayBodyTemp(String bodyTemp) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyTempInfoArray);
        textView.setText(bodyTemp);
    }
```

Device Storage screenshot of temp.txt, which is accessible with that code, and bodyTempTest.txt inside of download folder which isn't accessible with that code.

[temp.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48jRb.png)

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeX3n.png)

[inside folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0itZg.png)

Comment: Have you tried `"Download/bodyTempTest-1.txt"`?

Comment: I am a dummy that fixed it! thank you!

Comment: No problem! Best of luck with your app.